# android: image in icon not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm trying to place a banner at the top of a listview, one that stays there when the list scrolls down. The layout I currently have actually show what I want in the preview but when I run it in the emulator the only thing that appears is the list.

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/edinburghcrest"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EdUniCrest" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:text="Hotels Nearby" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center" android:textSize="20dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EdUniCrest"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EdUniCrest"
    android:background="#25476C"></TextView>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/listcolor" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

            <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/no_lunchs" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyway, I can't see why it isn't working. Does anyone have any idea what it might be?

Thanks.

Comment: When you want to stack views, Framelayout would be the ideal way to go. Try it out. If are having trouble using it, then someone will help you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RelativeLayout here just makes it confusing. You can achieve this simply with a couple of LinearLayouts. Wrap your banner in a horizontal layout with a height=wrap_content and set you ListView to height=fill_parent. The list will then fill all available space. The List will scroll independently of the rest of the page.

Something like below should work:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/bannerBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/edinburghcrest"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EdUniCrest"/>
       <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:text="Hotels Nearby" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center" android:textSize="20dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#25476C"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/no_lunchs" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I managed to get it working with the layout someone suggested earlier using FrameLayout. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrapped your `RelativeLayout` in a `ScrollView`, and since a `ScrollView` can only have one child, put the banner above it?